# Fancy scroll effect

Tags: javascript, animation, hyperlink, scroll

Does anyone know how they did that effect?

[Check this link.](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/)

If you click on a menu item on the left side, the window scrolls to the top before the new site is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: i can do the scrolling but i want that kind of effect when you click on a link. the targetted page should then open.